# How to update ParentView after updating SubView @ObservedObject SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

This is a simple example for my case.
I have a @ObservedObject viewModel (Object1), pass a property (Object2) to another view (View2) . Change value in View 2, and when i go back to View 1, i wish the value is updated too. What is the best solution?

In this Example, when i press the blue number, i wish black number is also updated.
Actually I don't know why do the black number is updated after pressing button "Show".
I would really appreciate if you could help me. Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var object1: Object1 = Object1(ob: Object2(n: 0))
    @State var isShow = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(object1.object2.n)")
                //NavigationLink(destination: View2(object2: object1.object2)) {
                //     Text("Go to  view 2")
                //}   
                View2(object2: object1.object2)
                
                Button {
                    isShow = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show")
                }.alert(isPresented: $isShow, content: {
                    Alert(title: Text("\(object1.object2.n)"))
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var object2: Object2
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            object2.n += 1
        } label: {
            Text("\(object2.n)")
        }


    }
}

class Object1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var object2: Object2
    
    init(ob: Object2) {
        self.object2 = ob
    }
}

class Object2: ObservableObject {
    @Published var n: Int = 0
    init(n: Int) {
        self.n = n
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(object1.object2.n)")
                   .onChange(of: object1.object2.n) { _ in
                       object1.objectWillChange.send()
                   }

// .. other code
```

Alternate is to move every `object2` dependent part into separated subview observed `object2` explicitly.

Comment: I have just tried in Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.1, still nothing change. I am finding a solution for iOS 13. Thank you so much.